# Error when try commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am working in a project and we are using TortoiseSVN for control version. We are a small team (five peoples) and i am experiencing a strange behavior when i uses "Show Log" or when i try commit.

**This problem only happen on my computer**, the function "**Show logs**" is not showing the most recent commits. i checked the date range and is wrong, but i can't change it for a date more recent.

Also, when i try commit something a get this error:

```
Commit failed (details follow):
Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 255) with output:
open_root:
SVN::Delta::Editor=HASH(0x3710a48),17882,_p_apr_pool_t=SCALAR(0x3c13c40)
open_directory:
SVN::Delta::Editor=HASH(0x3710a48),Android,_p_void=SCALAR(0x3c52af8),17882,_p_apr_pool_t=SCALAR(0x3c13c58)

open_directory:
SVN::Delta::Editor=HASH(0x3710a48),Android/trunk,_p_void=SCALAR(0x3c52bd0),17882,_p_apr_pool_t=SCALAR(0x3c13c58)

open_file:
SVN::Delta::Editor=HASH(0x3710a48),Android/trunk/ReadMe.txt,_p_void=SCALAR(0x3c52ba0),17882,_p_apr_pool_t=SCALAR(0x3c13c58)

No user associated with filesystem: Cannot verify lock on path
'/Project/trunk/master/gfx/Spr.spt'; no
username available at /usr/share/perl5/SVK/Editor/ByPass.pm line 87
DESTROY: SVN::Delta::Editor=HASH(0x3710a48)
```

I tried this with no successs:

- Resintall TortoiseSVN
- Install the most recent TortoiseSVN
- Redownload the brach

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: Try forcibly unlocking the file. This looks like it may be caused by `SVK`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem:

> ***Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 255) with output:***

The person responsible for setting up Subversion in your company has created a pre-commit hook that executes before Subversion allows your commit to go through. If that pre-commit hook exits with a `0` error code, your commit goes through. Otherwise, it doesn't.

This exit code (255) is usually associated with a bad pre-commit hook that is careening out of control. There is nothing you personally can do. Instead contact the Subversion administrator and show them this output. They need to fix their pre-commit hook, or completely remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error today.

> Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 255) with output:

Found out my issue was due to the comments I was entering. Removing brackets and quotes from comments cleared up the error.